# How to layer greenscreen footage over existing footage in the VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transparency, render-layers, layers

So I have a series of clips in the VSE (audio, video, what have you) and I have greenscreen footage where the green color has been removed using the keying node.

This is the footage I have.
[image: VSE image]

And this is the greenscreen clip I'm trying to layer over the others. (backdrop behind nodes shows what I want the clip result to be, just the model)
[image: GS backdrop]

My question is, how can I then use the existing footage I have as a backdrop and add/layer the new clip w/ greenscreen removed over it?

Do/can I use the Alpha Over node? Or do I have to render the greenscreen footage separately, then import that clip and layer it over the existing footage? I'm unable to figure out how to render it with no background by doing it this way.

I know how to use Alpha Over with images; I'm just not sure how to do it with video/footage.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out?

Comment: Check out this previous related question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78947/how-can-i-do-color-keying-using-the-vse