# VSE: Can you make a script to code in more filters? (add/multiply/subtract)

Tags: scripting, video-sequence-editor

So specifically in blender you have 3 settings really: add/subtract/multiply. Image editors such as gimp give you these and a total of 21 setting.

Are these settings in blender just a mashup of modifier settings applied across 2 strips? Or is there some kind of generic coding that all programs share for these settings? Add/subtract/multiply are found across all programs really for example.
I was just curious if the other filters from gimp could be put into blender via a script.

Kinda open ended given I don't know how to script for blender, but just curious if any insights. If each filter has a generically shared code then I'm guessing you could just make a new filter name for blender and plop in these codes for each?

[image]

[image]

Comment: VSE is not very FX complete as the compositor is designed for these workflows. Although you can use the math functions available in conjunction with the effect strip modifiers, like color and blur.

Comment: Also you can make things like a chromakeyed in the VSE by playing with these functions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78947/how-can-i-do-color-keying-using-the-vse

Comment: I'm aware of that stuff, it's not enough.

Comment: Well because all the functions you are suggesting are already in he compositor they probably won't ever be coded in the VSE. You can round trip media through a compositor scene and use that scene strip.

Comment: That too much hassle and bulk to 'roundtrip' video strips into the compositor and back into my vse for the sake of getting a few filter effects. Also if they took the time to include 3 of them into the vse already, I don't see the logic in not including the others into the vse in the future. But I do see the logic in never expecting that to happen via official versions due to nobody is developing the vse anymore.

Comment: I just looked again and found this commit https://developer.blender.org/D2872 then checked my version of Blender and.... drum roll... they're all there! Maybe just grab a latest build?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out your build of Blender may be old. 
They were updated as of this commit https://developer.blender.org/D2872
In fact there are a bunch of new blend types available.

[image: Blend type VSE strip]

Comment: I don't understand. I updated to 2.79b and my blend settings are the same as the old one. What am I missing?

Comment: I was using 2.79, the one back in october 2017. I specifcally asked them over at blender support chat what would happen if I updated to 2.79b a while back. They were unable to answer, and in the end stated it would just create another version of blender I could choose to load rather than update the 2.79 version. Well they were wrong, go figure...it simply updated my 2.79 to 2.79b. i still don't have those blend setting though, nothing has changed really other than the splash screen saying 2.79b now instead of 2.79

Comment: The wiki doesn't show or even tell the different blend settings. The link you provided seems to have the rawr update scripts but I don't want to go that method.....why is mine different than yours this is confusing me. I can't find any addons or settings under preferences to explain.

Comment: urs says 2.79.4 though...and mine only says 2.79 still though (pic above). i restarted computer, still no change.

Comment: okay in my add remove programs bar it says the blender installed was 2.79.2. Is 2.79.4 because you run on a different OS then? I'm using windows 8.1 64 bit. I just downloaded via the official site using the sole download option it provides. I had 2.79 which it says cameout in september last year.....makes sense. then 2.79b which it says i have was out in march this year. so....?!!?!!?https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't bother with official build, rather I use the development builds. They have all the bug fixes.

Comment: Could you walk me through how to get this? Like is there a page with the development builds...? I get stupidly lost looking through blender's logs and trying to find basic information much less download link. Is there a page with 2.79.4 I can download...? To be honest I don't really get this stuff and I'd rather just have the stable version, and just these blender settings here. Cause I'm guessing there would be a reason they were development builds (incomplete/unstable/etc). Can you walk me through how to get these blends specifically? I know how to install addons as .py, but that's it.

Comment: Is this the one you are using? blender-2.79-bb98e83b99e-win64.zip 119.72MB Jul 24 2018 02:40:39 https://builder.blender.org/download/? Are you able to revert back to the stabler versions if you run into problems? Do you have to uninstall first or can you just reinstall overtop of the unstable newer version? If you uninstalll and reinstall the older version does it affect your exisitng .blend project files? im in the middle of project is all...using unstable build not a good idea probably, but having just those blends in conjunction with the stable release would be worth it.

Comment: I just download the zip, unpack it into a folder I can keep track of and hit run on the Blender.exe. No install required, it should remember your previous settings as well. If it doesn't work well, just go back to the previous version. Bear in mind that some stuff in the .blend file might break going back a version.

Comment: As I stated, I don't know how to go back to a previous version the 'intended' way. And the fact some stuff might break even if I do go back or even go forward with the next release or even in the current version.....is making this a no until I know more. If it functioned more like an addon and the features uninstalled and installed independently....then sure i'd try them, since that kinda process is readily understood. I won't hold my breath waiting, as I can easily see this functionality being delayed or scrapped for countless reasons. We need more independently-regulated addons for the vse.